# Relative path being added to fetch request

Tags: reactjs, react-router, fetch, create-react-app, react-router-dom

I am making a react app using `create-react-app` and `react-router-dom 4`. My issue is, when I load a URL other than the default "/", the relative path gets prepended to requests being made.

For instance if I enter `mysite.com/templates` into the url searchbar, my fetch request `fetch("templates/item.json")` requests the url: `mysite.com/templates/templates/item.json` but if I navigate from the homepage to to `/templates` using the  `Link` component from react-router-dom this isn't the case.

Is there any way to avoid the relative path being prepended to the fetch request?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`fetch` will load the path relative to the url you have opened if you don't begin with `/` or specify absolute url.

If order to fetch always from `https://www.yourdomain.com/templates/item.json`, you should modify your fetch request to -> `fetch("/templates/item.json")`

or

specify the absolute url -> `fetch("https://www.yourdomain.com/templates/item.json")`